# how can I upsert documents in opensearch by python api

Tags: python, opensearch

I tried to upsert a document to Opensearch, that means if no id exists it would insert the document, if the id already exists then it would update the document(not overwritten).

For example, if the doc already in Opensearch `{"id":1,"name":"Jack"}`, when I upserted `{"id":1,"job":"engineer"}`, the document in opensearch would become `{"id":1,"name":"Jack","job":"engineer"}`, not just overwritten.

I tried python index api with doc_as_upsert as following, but it failed:

```
pyClient.index(
            index = indexName,
            body = document,
            id = document['id'],
            refresh = True,
            doc_as_upsert = True
        )
```

The document object is: {"id":"123","name":"Jack","job":"Engineer"}

Comment: _"I tried python index api with doc_as_upsert as following, but it failed"_. How exactly did it fail?

Comment: it says: doesn't support the doc_as_upsert action.

Answer (score 3):

1. Instead of `index`, you should use the `update` method
2. You're passing the `doc_as_upsert` incorrectly. The [documentation](https://opensearch-project.github.io/opensearch-py/_modules/opensearchpy/client.html#OpenSearch.update) for the `update` function highlights that fact.

The correct way to pass it would be:

```py
document = {"id":1,"job":"engineer"}
body = {"doc": document, "doc_as_upsert": True}
pyClient.update(
            index = indexName,
            body = body,
            id = document['id'],
            refresh = True
        )
```

Comment: thank you for providing the docs, they're so hard to find!

Answer (score 0):

try with index = document['_index'],body = document[_source] instead of index = indexName,body = document

Comment: hi SRama, I didn't get your point, The document object is: {"id":"123","name":"Jack","job":"Engineer"}.